# Is this an example of integration by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm attempting to understand how the following equation has been evaluated :

$$
\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-2x}dx = 
\left[\frac{x^2e^{-2x}}{(-2)}\right]_0^\infty+\int xe^{-2x}dx
$$

In other words how to calculate : 
$$ 
\left[\frac{x^2e^{-2x}}{(-2)}\right]_0^\infty+\int xe^{-2x}dx
$$

from :

$$
\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-2x}dx
$$
Reading about integration by parts :

https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/integration-by-parts.html

so instead of adding the terms they should be subtracted ?

Can provide steps as to how $$ 
\left[\frac{x^2e^{-2x}}{(-2)}\right]_0^\infty+\int xe^{-2x}dx
$$ has been determined ?

Comment: in fact the 2nd term is subtracted, but being multiplied by $-2/2$ it becomes added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They set $\; u=x^2$, $\;\mathrm dv=\mathrm e^{-2x}\mathrm dx$, so that
$$\mathrm d u=2x\,\mathrm dx,\quad v=-\frac12\mathrm e^{-2x}$$
 and they used in integration by parts formula:
$$\int_0^\infty\!\! u\,\mathrm dv=uv\biggm\vert_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty\!\! v\,\mathrm du.$$